# Efficient solution of matrix product equality in MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

I have the following matrix equation in MATLAB: [image: formula]

In the subscript in brackets I have written the matrix size.
I know N, Kt and P and need to solve this equation for the vector Lambda.

The straightforward but slow/naive approach would be:

```
A = N*inv(Kt)*N';
Lambda = A\P;
```

What is the most efficient way in which I can solve this equation? It is generally strongly discouraged to use inv(Kt) in Matlab, so what alternative ways might I be able to solve this problem? An attempt that I have made (although I don't know if it is any good, I haven't clocked it) is:

```
inv_Kt = Kt\speye(size(Kt));
A = N*inv_Kt*N';
Lambda = A\P;
```

Comment: LU decomposition is generally faster than inv() or pinv(). You can give it a chance.

Comment: @Kobye are there any special properties to N or K other than the dims specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\` to find the inverse is the generally recommended method. Without exploiting any special structures of the matrices I'd simply do this

```
Lambda=(N*(Kt\N.'))\P
```